# Save value in array with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

What's wrong with the code below?

```
var activity;
    angular.forEach(planning, function(value,key){
       activity = value.data
       $scope.registration.push(
         {"uuid": activity.id,
         "type": activity.type
         }
       );
    }
```

All registration array's fields are equals to last value.

Comment: While it's a good idea to declare `activity` within the iterator function, it won't make a difference here since angular calls the iterator synchronously and in-order. Something must have gone wrong with your `planning` variable. Can you describe where it comes from?

Comment: Looks okay to me, Can you check this plnkr "http://plnkr.co/edit/xAyI6v1aeJGNvpdboqyP?p=preview". I've constructed planning variable depending on what you code is expecting it to be, so please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally to declare activity within loop function resolves my problem.

```
angular.forEach(planning, function(value,key){
   var activity;
   activity = value.data
   $scope.registration.push(
     {"uuid": activity.id,
     "type": activity.type
     }
   );
}
```